# Randomly partitioning the unit interval with continuous functions

Tags: pr.probability, partitions

I want to construct a family of continuous functions $H$ in order to randomly partition the unit interval.

That is, consider a partition $\lambda$ of the unit interval into $n$ subintervals:
$\lambda = \{[0, \frac{1}{n}), [\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}),...,[\frac{n-1}{n}, 1]\}$, I am looking for a
probability distribution over functions ${h \in H}$ such that for any $x,y \in [0,1]$ which belong to distinct subintervals

$$
  Pr_{h \in H}[h(x) < 0 \land h(y) < 0 \; \vert \; I_x \neq I_y] = \frac{1}{4}
$$

where $I_x$ is the interval containing $x$.  In other words each interval will be
mapped randomly and independently to $0$ or $1$ with probability 0.5.

The setup here is very similar to that found in [k-wise independent hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-independent_hashing) (with $k=2$) ${h \in H}$, whereby we simulate "true" hash by sampling from a distribution over a hash family. The differences here are that:

- $h$ maps from the reals and should be a continuous function or piecewise continuous.
- I would like the function to be compact in representation.
  In other words, consider one possible approach which would sample a uniformly distributed value for each Interval $c(I) \sim \mathcal{U}(-1,1)$ then define
  $h(x) = c(I_x)$.  This approach is not viable for me because $h(x)$ is effectively a (possibly very) large table and not compact.
- $h$ should be closed form and efficiently computable in practice.

The motivation of this problem is to uniformly sample from a partition of arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Do you want continuous functions or piecewise constant functions? Why do you use $w$ and not $1/n$?

Comment: Preferably continuous but compactness of representation is perhaps the biggest requirement (apologies if this is a vague concept.  These functions will be used by nonlinear constraint solvers).  You're correct, there's no reason to have $w$ and $n$.